# How to remember or apply Num Lock state based on which keyboard is connected?

Tags: usb, kde, keyboard, desktop, numlock

I use my laptop on 2 different desks, both with different external keyboards. One of them I generally use with Num Lock on, the other with Num Lock off ([the only arrows it has are in the numpad](https://cdn.coolermaster.com/media/assets/1065/red-3-zoom.png), it's kinda weird but it's what I've got).

Is there a way to:

- Ideally, let the system remember a separate Num Lock state for each keyboard?
- Or to simply apply the preferred state when the keyboard is plugged in or the system boots with the keyboard connected?

I'm on an up-to-date Arch Linux with KDE.